# Check the exact location of each other any moment of time

Tags: applications

we have two android items one is nexus 5 phone with 3G connection with my younger brother and other one is nexus7 tablet with wi-fi only (with me) and both are in different cities.We both are connected to internet through our device .can I check each others exact location any moment of time? if we can then which App we need to use in india?

Answer (score 6):

From [Google+ help](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2998354?hl=en)

> Google+ allows you to share your current location with the people and
>   circles you choose across Google products such as Google+ and Google
>   Now. Once you've enabled Location Sharing, Google shares your best
>   available location.
>
> You can share your pinpoint or city-level location with others, and
>   you can do so on a circle-by-circle basis. For example: you can share
>   your pinpoint location with family, and your city-level location with
>   your co-workers. You can also change who can see your location or
>   completely turn off Location Sharing at any time.
>
> To use Location Sharing, you need to:
>
> ```
> Turn Location Reporting on from a compatible device [Android] [iOS]. 
> Enable Location Sharing and choose who can see your location.
> ```
>
> Turning on Location Reporting alone will not automatically share your
>   location; both of these steps need to be taken for Location Sharing to
>   work. Manage Location Sharing Turn Location Sharing on or off on
>   Android
>
> ```
> Open the Google+ application.
> From Home, touch Menu > Settings.
> Touch the account for which you'd like to turn Location Sharing on or off.
> Select Location sharing.
> Touch the switch next to Location Sharing to turn it On or Off. Turning off Location Sharing turns off sharing for both your pinpoint
> ```
>
> location and city-level location.
>       To share your precise location, touch Choose people to share with on the "Pinpoint Location" card.
>       To share your current city location, touch Choose people to share with on the "City Location" card.
>       Select OK.
>
> If you don't edit your "Pinpoint Location" or "City Location" sharing
>   settings, by default, your location is shared with "Only you."
>   Where does my location appear?
>
> People you choose to share location information with will be able to
>   see your current location on Google products. For example, on your
>   Google+ profile, it's displayed below your name and profile photo on
>   Desktop, Android, and iOS devices. On Android and iOS, they'll be able
>   to see your [location on a map](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/3302509) in the Locations destination in the
>   Google+ app.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is Google's device manager app (search in play store). It lets you see the location of other Google devices registered to your account. It's primary aim is for device security. E.g. location if stolen or lost, remote wipe, make the other device ring.

If the two devices belong to different people, you can have more than one Google account set up on your android device (via Settings -> Accounts). Just get the other person to add their account to your device (but turn off the data syncing options unless you want all their email, contacts, etc) if you want to view their location in device manager.

My wife and I use it all the time to see where the other is, e.g. find out when to expect them home, or where I am while out cycling for safety. Also viewable in a web browser from a pc.

Comment: This seems like an awfully kludgy way to do things, especially considering you have to give someone else your account credentials (and, obviously, access to all the information in your account). What's the benefit of doing this when Google+ has it built-in, and there are [other apps](http://www.cnet.com/news/six-ways-to-share-your-exact-location-with-family-and-why/) for it as well?

Comment: I think g+ requires you to manually check in or share your location. Device manager allows another device to query your location without any input required on your end.

Comment: Once you enable location sharing it updates it automatically. It's essentially a replacement for Latitude. Other third-party apps work similarly.